# Changing to Shared Primary Key on Existing DB?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first

I have an existing table structure that looks something like this:

```
AnimalTable
-------------
|Id         |
|Color      |
|Weight     |
|AnimalType |
-------------

CatTable
----------------
|Id            |
|MeowSound     |
|AnimalTableId |
----------------

DogTable
----------------
|Id            |
|BarkSound     |
|AnimalTableId |
----------------
```

`AnimalType` is either "Cat" or "Dog". Basically, it's a "Table Per Type" structure plus the additional "AnimalType" discriminator in the AnimalTable. This is obviously a contrived example, but my project has a similar setup that has been in use for a good amount of time. We're starting to convert some stuff over to use the EF Code First approach, and I'd like to use this same schema so I have an abstract `Animal` class, and concrete `Cat` and `Dog` classes.

Setting this up from scratch seems pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about changing the primary keys on my existing tables to make it as if I had been using EF all along. Has anyone done this and can provide some tips/direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a stored procedure that essentially dropped the `Id` column in the `CatTable` and `DogTable`, renamed `AnimalTableId` to `Id`, and made that the primary key. Sounds easy enough, but the hard part was writing something that would generically fix all the foreign keys already pointed at `CatTable.Id` and `DogTable.Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade scripts.

You'll face the same decision in the future with other changes of the schema. In your development you can refactor the classes and let EF generate the database for you. When you move to production you also need to produce a script that upgrades production.

To change the primary keys use:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'CatTable.Id', 'AnimalTableId', 'COLUMN';
```